# Android Studio - Cannot resolve symbol 'R' after adding package

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, package

Just added a class in a new package, I'm following this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/ tutorial for an expandlistview

New package called com.tutorial.expandListView and I added this line at the top of the new class ExpandListAdapter in com.tutorial.expandListView.Adapter

```
import com.tutorial.expandListView.R;
```

here's a screenshot of exactly what I'm doing
[image]

And I'm getting 'could not resolve symbol R' error.
To be clear, I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, syncing with gradle, closing and opening AS, checked all my updates, made sure I had SDK Build Tools installed, checked for errors in my .xml files, but none of these have done anything. I'd appreciate any suggestions i could get! this is getting very frustrating ><

Edit: Ive rewritten everything without the use of new packages. I'm fairly new to mobile development and AS so I think I might not have a great understanding yet. Thank you all for the suggestions

Comment: share the code of that class

Comment: What do you mean wherever it asks? I remove the line and still have errors wherever I'm referencing 'R'

Answer (score 0):

import com.tutorial.expandListView.Adapter.R;

You dont define all class path.Try this:)

Answer (score 0):

Try clean your project and sync again

Comment: I supposing it before. It doesnt useful for him:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **File --> Invalidate caches** then restart AS?